# Play Framework How can i pass collection to action create()?

Tags: collections, parameters, playframework

I am starter with Play Framework. I got a problem when i passed parameters.
I want to pass a collection from view to controller. And i do not know how to do this. I always get "null" when i get a collection from view.
My code below: 
    **Code in controller:**

```
public static void create(List<Book> books) throws Exception {
     for(Book book : books){
          System.out.println(book.get(0).author) // i got null :(
     }
}
```

**Code in HTML**

```
Book 1:
<input type="text" name="books.author" />
<input type="text" name="books.title" />
Book 2:
<input type="text" name="books.author" />
<input type="text" name="books.title" />
```

When i submit, i want to add 2 records into database include Book1 and Book2. Please support me

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this work by simplying add the array indicator to your HTML code

```
Book 1:
<input type="text" name="books[0].author" />
<input type="text" name="books[0].title" />
Book 2:
<input type="text" name="books[1].author" />
<input type="text" name="books[1].title" />
```

I have tested this solution, and it works fine.

Also note that your println will not compile, as you are calling `get(0)` on the Book object, and not the List object. If you just println `book.author`, it outputs the author as required.

Comment: Problem is that i do not know how many book will be submitted. Sometimes 2 or 5 or more. So, is there any another way instead of index each book?

Comment: You could do something with javascript, so for each new book, you could output the code, so that it had the correct index identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs an example of the Javascript for dyanmically adding and removing books (JQUERY needed):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var bookCount=0;
        $('#btnAddBook').click(function() {
            bookCount++;
            //newElem = go up a to the parent div then grab the previous container
            var newElem = $(this).parent().prev().clone().attr('id', 'book[' + bookCount + ']');
            //for each input inside the div, change the index to the latest bookCount
            $(newElem).find("input").each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var leftBracket = name.indexOf("[");
                var rightBracket = name.indexOf("]");
                var beforeBracketString = name.substring(0,leftBracket+1);//+1 to include the bracket
                var afterBracketString = name.substring(rightBracket);
                $(this).attr('name', beforeBracketString + bookCount + afterBracketString);
            });
            //insert it at the end of the books
            $(this).parent().prev().after(newElem);
            $(newElem).find("input").each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + bookCount);
                });
            //enable the remove button
            $('#btnRemovebook').removeAttr('disabled');
            //If we are at 16 divs, disable the add button
            if (bookCount == 15)
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
        $('#btnRemoveBook').click(function() {
            bookCount--;
            //remove the last book div
            $(this).parent().prev().remove();
            //in case add was disabled, enable it
            $('#btnAddbook').removeAttr('disabled');
            //never let them remove the last book div
            if (bookCount == 0)
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });
</script> 
<!-- HTML Snippet -->
<div id="book[0]">
    <label> Book: </label>
    <input type="text" name="books[0].author" value="Author" />
    <input type="text" name="books[0].title" value="Title" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAddbook" value="Add another book" />
    <input type="button" id="btnRemovebook" value="Remove last book" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
<!-- REST of the HTML -->
```